# how we select wifi in raspberry pi through keyboard

Tags: raspberry-pi

We want to connect wifi through a shortcut of keyboard just pressing key from keyboard wifi listing appear. Then we select SSID and fill password and connect with network. We are using this method but not working right now

```xml
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-q">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>wlan0</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=177585 might be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
<keybind key="A-q">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>wlan0</command>
  </action>
</keybind
```

try this, getting rid of the top and botttom `</keybind>`

If doesn't work, check out this on trying to set up keybinds:
http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Key_bindings

Comment: Thanks, but we try this but this does not work for me